# Editing shadow DOM in Ionic `ion-item`

Tags: css, ionic-framework, overflow

I have implemented a table, which is very wide (much wider than the screen), and the user can scroll horizontally.

At the far left, is a task-row component which has an element with a “sticky” header (.task-row_main class), which doesn't move when scrolling horizontally, by using the css position: sticky.

```
.task-row_main {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    max-width: 230px;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    left: 1px;
}
```

When I add my task-row component into ion-item, the sticky header breaks. Scrolling horizontally causes the sticky header to scroll off screen.

```
<ion-item>
    <task-row>
    </task-row>
</ion-item>
```

The reason this happens is because of shadow DOM styling:

[image]

When I look into it, I notice why it's not working, because of `overflow: hidden` on the `input-wrapper`:

```
.input-wrapper{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

How do I override input-wrapper's `overflow` property to set it to `visible`?

I've tried creating a directive and overwriting the css, but it didn't work:

directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  selector: '[appShadowCss]'
})
export class ShadowCssDirective implements OnChanges {
  @Input() shadowCustomCss: string;

  ngOnChanges(): void {
    const shadow = this.el.nativeElement.shadowRoot || this.el.nativeElement.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    if (shadow) {
      let innerHTML = '';
      innerHTML += '<style>';
      innerHTML += this.shadowCustomCss;
      innerHTML += '</style>';
      shadow.innerHTML += innerHTML;
    }
  }

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {

  }
}
```

html:

```
 `<ion-item appShadowCss shadowCustomCss='.input-wrapper{overflow:visible;}'>`
```

How do I edit this shadow DOM in `ion-item` to set `overflow: visible`?

Comment: did you do the wacky heing heing?

Comment: @cup_of yes and it was ineffective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there were more `overflow:hidden` instead of just in `input-wrapper{overflow:visible}`.

Had to do this:

`<ion-item #ionItem appShadowCss shadowCustomCss='.input-wrapper{overflow:visible;} .item-native{overflow:visible;} .item-inner{overflow:visible;}'>`