# Angular/Ionic: How can I apply custom class to an <ion-datetime-button> shadow dom element?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I would like to add a **custom css class** every time a value will change. Something like a *'dirty'* class to notify user the input has changed.

Here is my code:

```html
<div class="input-group mb-2">
 <ion-datetime-button
  datetime="begin"
  class="custom-datetime-button"
>
 <span slot="date-target" class="custom-date-target">{{
  begin
 }}</span>
 <span slot="time-target" class="custom-time-target">{{
  begin
 }}</span>
 </ion-datetime-button>
  <ion-modal
   [breakpoints]="[1]"
   [keepContentsMounted]="true"
  >
   <ng-template>
    <ion-datetime
     id="begin"
     [firstDayOfWeek]="1"
     showDefaultButtons]="true"
     [(ngModel)]="begin"
     [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }"
     (ngModelChange)="
      changeDatetime()"
    ></ion-datetime>
   </ng-template>
  </ion-modal>
</div>
```

Ionic generates a **Shadow Dom** with the button that I want to apply the CSS class to. Here is the HTML generated:

[image: Shadow Dom elements generated]

I have tried to use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56794910/editing-shadow-dom-in-ionic-ion-item) with a **custom directive** but it doesn't work:

```html
<ion-datetime-button
  datetime="begin"
  class="custom-datetime-button"
  appShadowCss
  shadowCustomCss="background: red;"
>
 <span slot="date-target" class="custom-date-target">{{
  begin
 }}</span>
 <span slot="time-target" class="custom-time-target">{{
  begin
 }}</span>
 </ion-datetime-button>
```

A solution [found here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-change-ion-datetime-button-background-color/229625) works but I want to apply the class dynamically when the input value changes.

```css
ion-datetime-button::part(native) {
    background: #FFF;
}
```